# alert-dismissible not closing wen clicking close button bootstrap laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

When I click the close button it doesn't close the notification. Am I missing something?

(The 'x' symbol at the upper right corner of the alert)

[image: Close button does not close the alert]

Here is the specific code of this alert. I'm using Laravel version 5.8.15 and latest bootstrap if that helps

```
<div class="mg-auto justify-content-center">
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="alert-heading">Oops! Something went wrong!</h4>
                <p>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        - {{ $error }}<br>
                    @endforeach
                </p>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
```

My script files alignment:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js.jquery-341.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: You should check if jQuery works on your page, maybe it is `asset('js/jquery-341.js')` instead of `asset('js.jquery-341.js')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure you correctly integrated [bootstrap's javascript plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js)? You have to call it after you called jQuery like so :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="mg-auto justify-content-center">
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="alert-heading">Oops! Something went wrong!</h4>
                <p>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        - {{ $error }}<br>
                    @endforeach
                </p>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Comment: I may have used the wrong bootstrap files. may I know what is the difference of the `bundle` one with just the `min` one?

Comment: The `bundle` one includes popper plugin which is used to display pop-ups but after testing on my side I realized you don't need it, I think the problem was with jQuery's integration, right? Because if you just put bootstrap's plugin without jQuery prior to it, it won't work.

Comment: More infos here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: IT may have been that I have not included the popper plugin. This may have caused the insufficiency of my code that is why it will not close. Good going.